# Which logic gate operation does the following circuit perform?

Tags: diodes, logic-gates

[image: Diode logic gate circuit]

It is given that 1 is for voltage greater than or equal to 5 V, while 0 is for voltage less or equal to 0 V. (A and B are the inputs.)

The answer is given as AND gate.

The trouble I am having is: given the way circuit is set up, \$V_{CC}=6V=V_{out}\$ (since these points are only connected by conducting wires, assumed 0 resistance.) Then, is the question correct? A solution I found on another site states "When A and B are both 1, the current flows through R and \$V_{out}\$ is 1."

[The question is from JEE Mains Online 2014 exam.]

Comment: Maybe you need to go in a full loop to know the voltages are the same ? Is it an AC circuit or DC?

Comment: Only that diagram and that information is given... But how does that affect V(out)=V(CC)?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember the equations used for amplifiers or differentials or semiconductors.

Comment: I agree with Photon below, must be a trick exam question.  From the web, remove the ground part completely and put the resistor at Vcc to make a proper AND.

Answer (score 5):

> Which logic gate operation does the following circuit perform?

[image]

**None.**

Vout is tied to Vcc, so will always be at the Vcc voltage by definition.  The inputs A and B have no bearing on the voltage of Vout.  The only thing they do is cause a additional roughly 100 mA each current to be drawn from Vcc when they are low.

Answer (score 1):

In the circuit you presented, Vout = Vcc = 6 V, and the values of the inputs at A and B are irrelevant.

If you saw a different explanation on some website, you should double-check that the circuit they analyzed is **exactly** the same as the one you are interested in.

To make a logical AND, you could remove the 10 kohm resistor between Vout and ground, and connect it between Vcc and the rest of the circuit.

Comment: As PhysicsDave suggests, your idea works. But is there any justification about why can it be changed so; or is the question incorrect?

Comment: By adding the resistor, you only weakly pull Vout to Vcc. If there's no current through the resistor then (by Ohm's law) Vout will be at the same potential as Vcc. If A or B is pulled low, then a current will flow through the resistor, so that there will be a potential difference across the resistor, and Vout will be at a low(ish) potential.

Comment: @Shubham1999, rejected your edit because ground is still relevant to the circuit as a reference for the other node potentials.

Answer (score 0):

> The answer is given as AND gate.

as wired, Vout is always Vcc so logic 1 output, regardless of what the input signal is.

if it is "normally" designed, the circuit you didn't show but likely meant to show here is an OR circuit for _A and _B -> it goes low if either A or B is low.

or it is an AND circuit for A and B.

Answer (score 0):

an AND gate should really look like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdJic7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>